# View slides up instead of curling with Model View Controller

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

```
    SignView *tempVC = [[SignView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignView" bundle:Nil];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self presentModalViewController:tempVC animated:YES];
[tempVC passDataWithString:button2.titleLabel.text andColor:currentlySelectedColor isNightModeOn:nightMode.on];
```

The view slides up instead of Curling up.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the transition style of a modal view controller, set it's modalTransitionStyle property.

```
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
```

Also note that some transition styles don't look right on the simulator, but should be fine on the device.

Comment: its on the simulator. can you verify that i didn't code it wrong?

Comment: zpastemack - thanks. im a noob. where would that code go? i added it in the same IBAction as the code above and it crashes. when I add it to viewDidLoad, the animation appears but it doesn't load the SignView